# Status of the process while Windows scheduler working

Tags: windows, batch, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I have a .bat file which should kick off every 30mins. I am using Windows scheduler for this. I have some questions on the same:

1. Does the scheduled task starts at a scheduled time even after a system reboot?
2. While the job runs, how can I display the progress of the status?
3. How to show the instance that's running in system tray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If it's scheduled, it should start as per the time/interval specified, although you can set it to run ASAP if it was skipped due to any reason:

   [image: 1]

   Check out all the other tabs of the task's `Properties` dialog, including `Conditions` etc.
2. The batch file should display a window when it's run, and you can print messages in it using the `echo` command or redirect `echo` messages to a text file. If you want to display a standard Windows message dialog, use something like [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) and check out how to use the `infobox` parameter with it [here](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd2.html).
3. Show instance of *what* running in the tray? Batch files don't run in the tray. If you're calling an app, set it so it doesn't run in the tray. To maximise an app already running in the tray, either the app needs to support some way of doing this (*some* apps for example maximise the running instance if you run them again), or you'd need to look into AutoIt/AutoHotKey scripting.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I am using XP and i dont have the tabs thats there in your screenshot...I am seeing in the following location. Control Panel --> Scheduled Tasks. Is that correct?      Also what happens on system reboot?

Comment: I don't quite remember what options were present in XP (screenshot is from Win7). Did you double-click the task you created to open its `Properties` dialog, as I mentioned? Edit: On reboot? If the task is missed and the option is selected, it will be run ASAP after logon. Otherwise it will run normally as per the schedule you have specified. Like I said, check the task's properties. Most options are quite obvious, and if not, you can always Google them for help or ask in a new thread here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should modify your app to LOG/REPORT status to a text file / event viewer.  Then you should make a separate app that runs in the system trade that is aware of the LOG and display that information to the user

Comment: Sorry i didnt quite understood that...I am new to scheduling aspects